# Heroku Deploy Error : No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.14

Tags: python, heroku, pip, anaconda, conda

I using trying to deploy an application built using python's Dash Framework to Heroku. Following the deploy instructions posted [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code).

I am having an issue when pushing to master repository. Conflict with anaconda installation it looks like.

```
Cmd: git push heroku master

Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r 
/tmp/build_7c37a8969b8001471e926143aa44a460/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r 
/tmp/build_7c37a8969b8001471e926143aa44a460/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from 
versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from 
-r /tmp/build_7c37a8969b8001471e926143aa44a460/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to stroom-dash.
remote: 

To https://git.heroku.com/stroom-dash.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/stroom-dash.git'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using Heroku's documentation to deploy with the Python buildpack which doesn't support a Conda runtime. The Heroku recommended approach is to use Docker (example [here](https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-miniconda)) to deploy a Conda runtime to Heroku.

Another option would be to simply use a [Conda buildpack](https://github.com/heroku-python/conda-buildpack) instead of the Docker image.

Comment: True. However, the Hereko container registry has been blacklisted.

Comment: I've added another link to a Conda buildpack if you can't resolve the Docker issues.