# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.14 error when deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I get this error when I try and deploy a flask application to Heroku. I can't find a solution that works. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling all packages with pip. Love some help thanks!

```
Beths-iMac:user-feedback-app bethwalsh$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 56, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
Writing objects: 100% (56/56), 3.71 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Total 56 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.7
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting alabaster==0.7.10 (from -r /tmp/build_6a5b669a64188c02d949bbd0ed931860/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/c3/9b7dcd8548cf2c00531763ba154e524af575e8f36701bacfe5bcadc67440/alabaster-0.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r /tmp/build_6a5b669a64188c02d949bbd0ed931860/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r /tmp/build_6a5b669a64188c02d949bbd0ed931860/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r /tmp/build_6a5b669a64188c02d949bbd0ed931860/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to user-feedback-app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/user-feedback-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/user-feedback-app.git'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku Deploy Error : No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825799/heroku-deploy-error-no-matching-distribution-found-for-anaconda-client-1-6-14)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369348/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anaconda+heroku